# org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to read json file from hive.

I an using [JsonSerde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) api to load json but getting an error

> ... 16 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray
>       at org.openx.data.jsonserde.objectinspector.JsonListObjectInspector.getList(JsonListObjectInspector.java:38)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:297)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:197)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.DelimitedJSONSerDe.serializeField(DelimitedJSONSerDe.java:60)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.doSerialize(LazySimpleSerDe.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.AbstractEncodingAwareSerDe.serialize(AbstractEncodingAwareSerDe.java:50)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DefaultFetchFormatter.convert(DefaultFetchFormatter.java:71)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DefaultFetchFormatter.convert(DefaultFetchFormatter.java:40)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ListSinkOperator.processOp(ListSinkOperator.java:87)

Does any one have any idea about how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to process Array, but you are given Object.

In Json:
Object is: `{...}`
Array is: `[...]`

Examples:
Accessing array:
`myArray[0]`
Accessing object: `myObject.myField`